# Find out last 7 days of upload images, last week uploaded image from Gallery and display them in different pages

Tags: php, attachments, html

In my Gallery, I have many pictures which are uploaded by the visitors of the site.

I want to show them in pages based on when the images were uploaded. E.g. 'Last 7 days', 'Last month', etc.

Comment: Would you please edit your question and show the code that you're currently using to display the images? It would also be helpful to provide information/code related to how the images are uploaded by visitors (are these attachments, posts, etc).

Comment: I need a plug in. If it could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've written a function for you-

```
function the_dramatist_get_post_by_time_range( $args = '' ) {
    $date_query = array();
    if ( $args === 'last 7 days') {
        $date_query = array(
            'after' => '1 week ago'
        );
    } else {
        $month_ini = new DateTime("first day of last month");
        $month_end = new DateTime("last day of last month");
        $date_query = array(
            array(
                'after' => $month_ini->format('Y-m-d'),
                'before' => $month_end->format('Y-m-d'),
            )
        );
    }
    $params = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
        'date_query' => $date_query
    );
    return get_posts($params);
}
```

Hope that's gonna help. It's gonna return you the posts object.
For 'Last 7 Days' use the function like-
`the_dramatist_get_post_by_time_range('last 7 days')`
and for "Last Month" use it as it is-
`the_dramatist_get_post_by_time_range()`

Please test it first wit various dates. If you find anything wrong please knock here. I think the date range can cause some problem. So please test it first.